# CoreMotion OperationQueue Issue on Apple Watch

Tags: swift, memory-management, apple-watch, nsoperationqueue, core-motion

Devices: iPhone 8, Apple Watch Series 3

I am currently working on a phone app + watch extension that streams CoreMotion data from all CoreMotion sensors using the standard APIs coupled with associated OperationQueues.

I need to be able to stream all CoreMotion sensors in parallel, write the samples to csvs, and then export them. Storing the samples in memory in an array caused memory pressure issues as expected, so now I am writing each sample directly to file as it is received - so for X=# of streaming sensors, I also have X files being written to, also on associated Operation Queues.

My streaming code looks like the following (e.g. for accel):

```
public func start(mm: CMMotionManager, fileQueue: OperationQueue, myOutputURL: URL) {
    if mm.isAccelerometerAvailable && !mm.isAccelerometerActive {
        mm.startAccelerometerUpdates(to: sampleQueue, withHandler: { (sample: CMLogItem?, error: Error?) in
        if let error = error as NSError? {
            print("There was a sampling error --- \(error.localizedDescription)")
        } else {
            if let accelerometerData = sample as? CMAccelerometerData {
                let now = Date().timeIntervalSince1970
                let sampleComponents: [Double] = [
                    now,
                    accelerometerData.timestamp,
                    accelerometerData.acceleration.x,
                    accelerometerData.acceleration.y,
                    accelerometerData.acceleration.z
                ]
                let row = sampleComponents.map({ String(format: "%.5f", $0) })
                let sampleString = row.joined(separator: ",") + "\n"
                if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: myOutputURL.path)
                    let writeOperation = BlockOperation(block: {
                        do {
                            if let utf8Sample = sampleString.data(using: .utf8) {
                                let fileHandle = try FileHandle(forWritingTo: myOutputURL)
                                fileHandle.seekToEndOfFile()
                                fileHandle.write(utf8Sample)
                                fileHandle.closeFile()
                            }
                        } catch let error as NSError {
                            print("There was an error while writing to file --- \(error.localizedDescription)")
                        }
                    })
                    if let lastOperation = fileQueue.operations.last {
                        writeOperation.addDependency(lastOperation)
                    }
                    fileQueue.addOperation(writeOperation)
                    print("Num OPs in Sample Queue: \(sampleQueue.operations.count)")
                    print("Num OPs in I/O Queue: \(fileQueue.operations.count)")
                }
            }
        })
    }
}
```

This works great...on the phone. The sampling operation queues rarely have anything over 100 total operations at any given time, and the file queues at most 5 - even when streaming for over an hour. However, I use the exact same code in my watchkit extension to stream accel and motion data, and something peculiar happens. The sample queues for the sensor data increase ad infinitum. In other words, it's as if the operations coming from the CoreMotion sampling are never dequeued from the sample queue.

Side Note: In addition to dependency chains, the queues are also configured with:

```
    sampleQueue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1
    fileQueue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1
```

In the hopes that samples are received and written in order.

This infinite increase causes the memory allocation to approach around 80MB after about 15 minutes of streaming, which I have empirically found to be an approximate upper bound for when my watch os terminates the extension due to too much pressure. I have logged the number of operations in the sample queue as each sample comes in and by the time it is approaching the 80MB mark, there are about 60-80k operations in the queue, while in the I/O queue the number is similar to that of the phone. I cannot understand why because it seems more intuitive that the bottlenecks would exist in the disk I/O queue not in the sample queue especially as file sizes and sample numbers increase.

I am curious as to whether or not others have experienced an issue like this and how they overcame it because it seems like this would be a fairly standard problem in storing and exporting sensor data from the Apple devices.

Specifically, I am curious as to how others have managed to stream and store sensor data over long periods of time on these devices for later analysis, and if you feel like something I am doing is incorrect. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think the key to this is to do as little processing as possible on the Watch itself.

This does not directly solve the issue, but what I did was to stream data from the Watch to the iPhone and have the processing to CSV done on the iPhone. This avoided having the Watch doing any heavy lifting (which is all the more important for older Watches).

Also, what is your updateInterval?

Comment: At the time I was firing on all cylinders at 100Hz for every sensor. I also, ended up doing something similar to what you mentioned. I used the applicationContext WatchConnectivity API to send samples to the phone in batches and wrote everything to file on the phone.

Comment: Thanks for following up - did you ever have a frame dropping issue when you were collecting at 100Hz? I doing something similar to you and find that I am missing data sometimes in my results. I explain this here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51254944/irregular-timestamp-in-cmmotionmanager

Do you have a repo of your code I could look at?